# SQL Select Date between Error conversion failed

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008

I have a column of data type `date`

When I run the following statements :

```
select count(*) as dt from dbo.logs where dateLogged>= '2018-02-01' and dateLogged < ='2018-02-30';
```

I get `Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.`

Comment: since when there are 30 days in February ?

Comment: do you try to use between in your query?!

Comment: @Squirrel OMG!!!!! how do I select your answer?

Comment: Can't, it is a comment. No worries.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Squirrel!!!

Answer (score 0):

```
select count(*) as dt from dbo.logs where CAST(dateLogged as date) >= '2018-02-01' and CAST(dateLogged as date) < ='2018-02-30'; 
OR
select count(*) as dt from dbo.logs where CAST(dateLogged as date) BETWEEN '2018-02-01' and '2018-02-30';
```

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bcode-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

'2018-02-30' IS NOT A VALID DATE. Replace that with a valid date and try the following query-:

```
select count(*) as dt from dbo.logs 
where cast(dateLogged as date) 
between '2018-02-01' and '2018-02-28';
```

Answer (score 0):

try this :->

set dateformat dmy

select count(*) as dt 
from dbo.logs 
where dateLogged>= '01-02-2018' and dateLogged < ='30-02-2018'

Answer (score 0):

Please try dateLogged  column convert into date you have two options

```
Cast(dateLogged  as datetime)
```

or

```
Convert(varchar(30),'7/7/2011',102)
```